# Scrolling UITextView without wrapping

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` in which I wish to display fixed width text that must not wrap unexpectedly, and which must provide scrolling if the text does not fit within the viewport.

With just a `UITextView` I don't appear to be able to prevent the text from wrapping.

I've also tried putting a (much larger) unscrollable `UITextView` inside a smaller `UIScrollView`.  That allows me to prevent the wrapping, but I then don't appear to be able to scroll.

What Storyboard properties must I change (or code should I add when updating the text) to get the scrolling to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by replacing the `UITextView` (and its containing `UIScrollView`) with a `UIWebView`, with the desired text contained within a `<pre>` block.

[for safety, the text inside the `<pre>` block is escaped first]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a tricky issue. What would the fixed format look like? Can you provide a fake example?

Though, if you want to put a textView in the scrollView using autolayout, it's not trivial.
See: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/

You have to set all constraints for the textView and then add an equal width constraint from the main view to the scroll view

On the other hand, you can use frame structure even in autolayout. You can create the scrollView by code and then add the textView as a subview, then calculate the content size, which is also a pain in the neck.

Comment: the format is just lines of output like you'd get from a UNIX command line utility (in fact that's exactly what it is)

Comment: Can you give a fake example?

Comment: The exact content doesn't matter - it's effectively just a text file that's rendered with a fixed-width font, but where there's too many columns (and/or rows) to fit inside the viewport.